# iframe adds html head and body

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a static html document with an iframe in its html code as this

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.1/test.php"></iframe>
```

and test.php simply echoes a line of text:

```
<?php
echo '
            <div class="notice">
                Welcome My friend
            </div>';
?>
```

What's strange however is that the iframe loads redundant code which I didn't add and which breaks the final DOM with a nested  element:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="login">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I avoid this extra unrequested html from being generated?

Comment: Its iframe's default behaviour...

Comment: What is the problem with this tags?

Comment: the final document has a starting <html> and a nested <html> generated by the iframe...

Comment: Please share link if possible...

Comment: So don't use iFrame and load content using `$.load`/`$.ajax`

Comment: Yes you can do this to avoid iframe. But iframe also is not breaking dom elements as i have used it so manu times...

Comment: Ok I avoided iframe and used jquery.. didn't realize iframe worked this way though...

Comment: iframe content is totally separate to the page it is held within that's why it has it's own html, head and body tags

Answer (score 1):

Iframe is used to embed another document within the current HTML document. So it is normal behavior of iframe tag. And you cannot handle [using CSS] or modify html code which rendered from iframe. So may be that causes your page is breaking.